# Div transparent for events

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have four `div` squares in a grid and fifth one overlaying them, in the center:

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TLFJh/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="info">info</div>
    <div id="inn1"></div>
    <div id="inn2"></div>
    <div id="inn3"></div>
    <div id="inn4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

#inn1, #inn2, #inn3, #inn4 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
#inn1 { background: blue; }
#inn2 { background: red; }
#inn3 { background: green; }
#inn4 { background: yellow; }

#info {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

With jQuery, I want to bind `mouseover()` event to the four squares (easy), but I want that they catch the event even if the pointer is over the *info* box (the box is somehow "transparent" for the events"). Is it possible?

**Edit**:

the goal is that I display some information pop-up, different for each `#inn` that follows the pointer, and the pop-ups should be also displayed when the cursor is over `info` but as it was over `inn`.

Comment: You can simplify your code greatly to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TLFJh/1/)

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that comes to mind is to compare mouse' position and block's position. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/7FTcT/).

Answer (score 0):

Is the jQuery event .mouseenter() what you're looking for?

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter

This will maintain the transparency when in child DIVS of the bound parent.

Comment: `info` div is not a child of colored divs

Comment: I need `mouseover()` because I need to track the pointer's position

Comment: @Jakub: If all you care about is position, why not just overlay one div over all the others?

Comment: @Eric: I have updated the description. I need the position _and_ information about the current div under the cursor

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B9ccB/7/). I took Eric's simplified html, added jquery.hoverIntent and added a few events so you can see the hover events being fired.
I got the hoverIntent plugin [here](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) for reference.

Comment: I updated your code, http://jsfiddle.net/B9ccB/4/ this is more what I would like (for `inn1`), my intention is that I have no "out" event when cursor is both over "inn" and "info"

Comment: doesn't it give better sample http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/2UjqR/6/ ? asdi understand it have to change text in debug if move mouse near middle of info div (intersepting borders) and yes - it does not

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to calculate which div the mouse is hovering? You can then just create one overlay div and calculate the target div with the mouse position from the event.

Comment: In the real page I will have dozens of not-so-regular divs, and all of them floating and with sizes specified with %. So unfortunately, no :(

Comment: Isn't it possible to do that using Javascript's [computed style](http://blog.stchur.com/2006/06/21/css-computed-style/)?